# how to logout from react navigation stacknavigation nested components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, native-base

i want to logout from a component inside a stacknavigator and the stacknavigator is inside a bottomtabsnavigator which is finally inside a stacknavigator that houses two switchnavigator

i tried this.props.navigation.navigate(component) and it failed and several other ways i am a bit stuck and frustrated any help will be greatly appreciated as i am new to react native and react navigation

```
const AddContactTab = createStackNavigator({
    AddContact: AddContactsActivity,
});
const ManageContactsTab = createStackNavigator({
    ManageContacts: ManageContactsActivity,
    viewContact: ViewSingleContactsActivity,
    editContacts: EditContactsActivity
});



const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
    ManageContacts: ManageContactsTab,
    AddContact: AddContactTab
}, {
    tabBarOptions: {
         activeBackgroundColor:'#3F51B5',
        activeTintColor:'#ccc',
        showLabel:false,
        style: {
            backgroundColor:'white',
            color:'white'
          },
          tabStyle:{
          },

        //   labelStyle:{
        //     color:'white',
        //     fontWeight: 'bolder',
        //     fontSize: 14
        //   }
    },
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        tabBarIcon: () => {
            const { routeName } = navigation.state;
            let tabName;
            tabName = routeName === 'AddContact' ? 'plus' : 'home';

            return  <Icon name={tabName} size={24} 

              color="grey" />


        }
    })
},

);
export default createAppContainer(Tabs);





const MainStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: HomeActivity },
    Register: {screen: RegistrationActivity}
  },
  {
      initialRouteName: 'Home',
  }
  );




  const AuthStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
      Dashboard: { screen: DashboardActivity },
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Dashboard',
    }
    ); 


    const RootStack = createSwitchNavigator({
      initialLoading: InitialLoadingActivity,
      auth: AuthStack,
      all: MainStack,
    }, 
    {
      initialRouteName: 'initialLoading',
  });
```

now i want to logout from addcontactsactivity to the initialroute of the AuthStack stack navigator....please if i am not clear enough let me know so i can edit my question

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to reset your present stack.
2. Set the present stack index to 0
3. Got to the parent stack which has access of all the screens
4. Navigate to that screen.

   import { StackActions, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

   ```
   const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
     index: 0,
     actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Profile' })],
   });
   this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
   ```

Edit : Use this if it works for you.

```
this.props.navigation.dispatch(
                  {
                      type: 'Navigation/NAVIGATE',
                      routeName: 'GoToANavigator',
                      action: {
                        type: 'Navigation/NAVIGATE',
                        routeName: 'GoToAScreenInANavigator',
                      }
                  }
                 );
```

[ref](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html#reset)

[ref 2](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/335)

Comment: this only moves to the initial route of the that stack it doesnt move to another stack

Answer (score 0):

Regarding documentation I guess you can try:

`this.props.navigation.dispatch(StackActions.popToTop())`

The popToTop action takes you back to the first screen in the stack, dismissing all the others.

[Documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html#poptotop)

Comment: this doesnt move out out of the stack it only gets to the initial stack for the stackroot i want to move out of the stack.